# Detect completed POST to iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, force-download

I'm posting some form data to an iFrame and the result is a Force Download file. I'm trying to detect when the download starts so I can reset some values in the form. I noticed in the Chrome console this event fires when the download starts:

[image: Chrome Console Event]

Is there a way to detect this event with Javascript?

Comment: what about the trigger that start the download? you probably have a button that send the post data, attach to this event your reset_form action.

Comment: Well, that's the trigger I'm using to display a spinner gif. I'm trying to find the event to remove the gif. Sometimes it takes a while for the download to start, depending on the number of records in the download file.

Comment: I should also note I've tried an $('#iframe').load() event and even a setInterval() checking the src of the iFrame to change from about:blank to the URL of my file, but the URL never changes and the load() event happens only once I believe when the page loads and doesn't happen again when on this force download script. I also want to mention that I'd prefer NOT to store these files on the server anywhere.